# Query to remove rows based on value of a column

Tags: excel, delete-row

I'm having a file with data as showing in the screenshot:

[image]

Need to build a query that will remove all rows with the same search ref, provided at least one row has a non-zero value. From the particular screenshot, all highlighted rows should be deleted, since there is at least one entry with Order_Placed=1.

Does anyone have an idea on whether same feasible?

Have applied a workaround with filtering out the rows with Order_Placed=1 and then vlookup the whole table, but would like a query like solution

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Yes it would. Actually the solution provided already below solved my inquiry. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Glad that it helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Power Query Solution**

Lets take a sample data like yours

[image]

- select your data
- <kbd>Data</kbd> tab click `get & transform` then `from table`
- a power query window will be opened

[image]

- create 2 new columns say `dat` and `dummy` by `group by` like this

[image]

- expand `dat` to get like this

[image]

- close and load data back to excel

[image]

Now you can easily filter out data by dummy column.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use VBA to achieve your goal. By using the code I wrote below, the rows which you want to be deleted will be deleted every time you open this excel. I reviewed the photo that you attached, my code will work only if you put your table through A1 cell. Otherwise the code may not work :)

I will explain how to add my code to your excel. If you know to use VBA you can skip this part:

From "Developer" tab, click on "Visual Basic". Then, click these in order: Insert , Module. Then you should paste the code below.

I hope It works, if you face any problem we can contact again. (Don't forget to save this file in macro-enabled ".xlsm" format!)

Note: If you review the code, in **three** places I wrote "**16**". You should modify this number according to your total row number. I used 16 to protect my computer from extra running problems :)

Have a nice day.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

    For i = 2 To 16
        If Cells(i, 3).Value = 1 Then
            For j = 2 To 16
                If Cells(j, 1).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                    Rows(j).Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    For i = 2 To 16
        Rows(i).Select
        If Rows(i).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            Selection.Delete
            i = i - 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Have implemented already the proposal by @AnilGoyal using Query

Best regards, Thanasis